# Installing Virtualbox 7.0 on Linux Mint 20.1

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox

I am attempting to install Virtualbox 7.0 on linux mint 20.1. I have tried downloading and installing via package manager and the debian file from oracle. No success either way. Here is the error I keep running into:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-7.0 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5help5 (>= 5.15.1) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.15.1) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1) but it is not installable
                  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 12) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
                  Depends: libvpx7 (>= 1.10.0) but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debian package you are attempting to install is not compatible with the distribution you are attempting to install it onto.  You would need to use one of the VirtualBox packages that is compatible with `libc6-2.31`.

You should be able to use `apt` to install `virtualbox` from the `multiverse` repository or you could download and attempt to install [the proper package for your distribution](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/7.0.8/virtualbox-7.0_7.0.8-156879%7EUbuntu%7Efocal_amd64.deb) since Linux Mint 20.1 is based on Ubuntu 20.04